# Cannot send push notifications iOS using APN Auth Key

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native

I attempting to send a push notification to my react native project. When sending to single device (provided FCM Token), it thrown an error

`Invalid APNs certificate. Check the certificate in Settings.`

So my assumption is the notification message is even not yet sent to APN, which my device obviously will not gonna receive anything

Please help

**edit**

I already uploaded my APN Authentication Key. Firebase docs says that I need to use either APN Authentication Key or APN Certificates

Comment: Hi Kevin, were you able to solve this? I am having the exact same problem.

Comment: I have solved this issue. The problem is from the apple configuration. I use the old p8 certificate

Comment: Please what do you mean by old p8 certificate? I thought using .p8 is the new way and .p12 is the old way? Thanks

Comment: @KevinDave @Grasim I'm having the same issue. p8 is definitely the new way and I'm getting the same `InvalidApnsCredential` error. I can curl APNS directly using the .p8 it works so definitely not a certificate issue, the issue is with Firebase connecting to APNS.

Comment: I got the same problem, especially when using different TeamIDs. All setup were correct (p8 Key, TeamID, KeyID). The solution for me was to generate a new server legacy key (Firebase -> Cloud Messaging -> First option)

Answer (score 3):

Revoking and re-uploading the key worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to push notification with no APNs Certification assign.

Please check the link below to generate or create the certificate to allow firebase send push notification in iOS.

> https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/certs

Here are the React-Native plugin and instruction for FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging)

> https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm

Hope it could help you.

Comment: So you should give us more detail to help...
Did u allow Notification in project XCode yet?

Comment: Yes. I already configure the Capabilites in Xcode to receive push notifications and in background notification. I also already update AppDelegate.m file